# How to translate escapehtml (Filter by)

Tags: magento2, php, csv, translate

Hello i cant to translate this one http://prntscr.com/kt3mrb

my code is

```
<div class="block-content filter-content">
        <?= $block->getChildHtml('state') ?>

        <?php if ($block->getLayer()->getState()->getFilters()): ?>
            <div class="block-actions filter-actions">
                <a href="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getClearUrl() ?>" class="action clear filter-clear"><span><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Clear All') ?></span></a>
            </div>
        <?php endif; ?>
        <?php $wrapOptions = false; ?>
        <?php foreach ($block->getFilters() as $filter): ?>
            <?php if (!$wrapOptions): ?>
                <strong role="heading" aria-level="2" class="block-subtitle filter-subtitle"><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Shopping Options') ?></strong>
                <dl class="filter-options" id="narrow-by-list">
            <?php $wrapOptions = true; endif; ?>
                <?php if ($filter->getItemsCount()): ?>
                    <dt role="heading" aria-level="3" class="filter-options-title"><?= $block->escapeHtml(__($filter->getName())) ?></dt>
                    <dd class="filter-options-content"><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getChildBlock('renderer')->render($filter) ?></dd>
                <?php endif; ?>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
        <?php if ($wrapOptions): ?>
            </dl>
        <?php endif; ?>
    </div>
```

and my translate is

```
"Filter","Φιλτράρετε με",module,Magento_Catalog
```

any suggest?

Comment: What is the actual text(attribute name) which is saved in admin? And how many languages you are using?

Comment: i have english and greek as languages from the attribute takes only By

Comment: What is the default language in admin?

Comment: they set greek as default...

Comment: ok, there is already an option to change the text by store view for every attributes.

Comment: yeap but the filter?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/83012/discussion-between-sukumar-gorai-and-darkattack).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the code you have used in your **view.phtml** you need to use the below code in your csv file:

```
Filter by "%1", YOUR TEXT "%1"
```

OR

```
Filter by '%1', YOUR TEXT '%1'
```